# How to add a list view to a tab in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that a similar question has been asked before but it doesn't really fit what I was looking for. Here it goes. I am trying to populate a tab with a list view however all the examples lead to using Intent in .setContent(), which does not fit what I am trying to do. So, here is what I did:

```
try {
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ratingSort").setIndicator("TAB 1",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_sort))
                  .setContent((TabContentFactory) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, ratingSort));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Log.e(err.toString(), "an error occurred...");
    }
```

I put in try-catch clause because it causes a runtime error. Apparently the error is in .setContent(), with the cast: ERROR/java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter(31530).

Here is the xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="rating_array">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Any ideas, help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast an `ArrayAdapter` to a `TabContentFactory`, any more than you can cast a `HashMap` to a `Double`.

If you want a `ListView` in a tab, either:

1. Put the `ListView` as a child of the `FrameLayout` in the layout file, then use the version of `setContent()` that takes a widget ID, or
2. Create an actual `TabContentFactory` implementation that, in `createTabContent()`, returns a newly-constructed `ListView` widget

In either case, you can call `setAdapter()` on your `ListView` to supply it with the `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: CommonsWare, this is very helpful thanks. In the context of the application that I am building, I already have a main activity that does a lot of stuff and when I click a button the view is set to gone and I make the tabs visible. I was able to do that with 2 separate activities. But my problem is whenever I click on an item I need to go back the first activity. So that is my problem